# I have 3 buttons, I want one of them to be in clicked state by default unless I click the other button in HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html

I want one button to be in clicked state by default unless I click on the other button. When I click the other button then everything should work like normal buttons.

Comment: You can't manually trigger the :active class of native button html element, you have to create a custom css class that emulates that look and toggle that.

Comment: Can you be more clear, i am just a beginner.

Comment: Have you heard of radio buttons?

Comment: You have to add your code, what you did so far, check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , specially the section about "Help others reproduce the problem"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something with CSS to emulate the active style, and use JS to trigger that CSS class:

```js
active.classList.add("active")
const btns = document.querySelectorAll("button")
btns.forEach((el, i) => {
  el.onclick = () => {
    el.classList.add("active")
    el.innerText = "Active"
    btns.forEach((el, j) => {
      if (i !== j) {
        el.classList.remove("active")
        el.innerText = "Non Active"
      }
    })
  }
})
```

```css
.active {
  border: 1px inset #DDD;
  background: rgb(245, 245, 245);
}
```

```html
<button id="active">Active</button>
<button>Non Active</button>
<button>Non Active</button>
```